# Clock is one hour too fast, how do I fix it?

Tags: time

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04. I am in Europe/Dublin timezone. My clock is one hour fast. I'm getting time off the Internet. Here is the output from dpkg-reconfigure tzdata at 15:41.

```
Current default time zone: 'Europe/Dublin'
Local time is now:      Thu Oct 11 16:41:54 IST 2012.
Universal Time is now:  Thu Oct 11 15:41:54 UTC 2012.
```

The time displayed in Ubuntu is the wrong, late one: 16:41.

Comment: Is daylight saving running in your City?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is "Daylight saving" is active in your area and this information is not available in Ubuntu's time server. Check that it is indeed the case.

<sup>This is confirmed by OP in a comment</sup>

Comment: Is there a fix?

Comment: I don't know about a good fix. I would simply change my timezone to myprevioustimezon+1.